# error: error creating unique temp file: Permission denied

Tags: logrotate

while executing logrotate script manually I am receiving an error as follows.
$ logrotate -vf  /apps/web/scripts/Logroate-web.conf

truncating /apps/oracle/admin/mserver/adf12dev/servers/adf_1/logs/udara_1.out
set default create context
error: error creating unique temp file: Permission denied

Please let me know why is that and how to eliminate . Please note I am running this script using non root. user.
thanks

Comment: Does your non-root user have permissions to write to that directory?

Answer (score 3):

I was receiving the same error running as non-root user; though this was not preventing logrotate from rotating my app logs.  In my case, I was attempting to write status to /dev/null:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -v -s /dev/null /path/to/logrotate.conf
```

Removing the -s option (writes to default status file, i.e. /var/lib/logrotate.status) resulted in the same error message.  Updating to a new path removed the error message:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -v -s /path/to/logrotate.status /path/to/logrotate.conf
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
logrotate -v -s  /rlsothrbackup/rlsspool/MERGEDSPL/log.status  --force /rlsothrbackup/rlsspool/MERGEDSPL/logrotate.cnf
```

This worked for me when I want the `log` to be rotated within `rlsothrbackup/rlsspool/MERGEDSPL/`

Comment: This cannot work for OP as he has "permission denied" error